# Run lumen/laravel without instantiating the whole app

Tags: laravel, lumen

I want to force my lumen project to run without instantiating the whole app.

For example when a route has been executed, like:

/test

when it is called, then it goes to somewhere that we defined it.

for instance: ExampleController@test

That's it.

I don't need any extra package or in fact I don't want the whole app created just for a simple request.

Is there any tool? or Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to reduce boilerplate code from every Framework, but consider Lumen as a reduced Laravel.

First read Laravel's Request Lifecycle from docs: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/lifecycle

Secondly, you should keep Facades, Eloquent and Services Providers commented and with this Lumen is lean as posible.

Comment: Thank you but I think you didn't get my question and your answer wasn't helpful. Thanks btw.